# Assign Field on a Particle System Slot

Tags: particles, force-fields, system

I wanted to know if there was a way to assign a Field to a Particle System Slot,

I have 3 different Fields and I would like some to act individually on 3 different Particle Slots on the same emitter
[image]

Comment: @Chris
but look what blender himself calls it Particle system slot

Comment: Oh really? Where? Never saw that 

Comment: if you stay with the pointer on the icon to add a particle system, it asks you if you want to add a new particle system Slot

Comment: Ah ok…didn’t know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your forces in collections.

Then you can use these collections in the particle settings as "effector collection". Only the forces in that collection will affect your particle system.

As you can see in the image i have two particle systems (red and blue), one has "Effectors1" as effector collection (red), so the particles react to my force field. The blue one has an empty collection as effector collection, so the particles just fall down without reacting to the force field.

[image]